# Can't Use _Queryall in DBAMP for custom object

Tags: dbamp

I am using DBAMP connection to Query custom objects in Salesforce from SQL database. I want to query deleted records and when i use the _queryall suffix for standard objects i get that. Howwever if i try that on a custom object I get an error:

> Blockquote
>   "sObject type 'My_Custom_Object__c_Queryall' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names."."
>   Blockquote

Has anyone experienced this issue? Am I using incorrect syntax for the QUeryAll?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be unrelated to custom VS standard objects. I had Queryall capitalized and SOQL did not like that.